# 20 books in 5 shleves

Tags: combinatorics

I have a question from my homework and I can't solve it.

How to arrange 20 books in 5 shelves if the order of books in each shelf matters?

I thought first that the answer is $5^{20}$, but that only counts the arranging of the books in the shelf if the order does not matter, but the number of shelf does. The thing that makes it difficult is that there can be any number of books in each shelf. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately we will multiply by $20!$ in order to deal with the ordering. But we need  to deal also with *how many* books each shelf will hold.

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ be the numbers of books to be placed on the various shelves. To find the number of ways to make the decision about *numbers*, we need to determine the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=20$$
in non-negative integers. This is a standard [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem.  The Wikipedia article gives a pretty good discussion of this problem.

It tuns out that there are $\dbinom{20+5-1}{5-1}$ solutions to the equation, and therefore $20!\dbinom{24}{4}$ ways to arrange the books.

Comment: I believe the binomial term in this solution is incorrect.  The value of $\binom{24}{5}$ is $42504$.  A brute force count of the number of solutions yields $10626$, which equals $\binom{24}{4}$

Comment: @User58220: Thanks for spotting it! You are right.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of looking at the problem:

Take your $20$ **distinct** books, and add $4$ **identical** "End of Shelf" markers.  These $24$ objects can be arranged in a row in  N distinct ways:$$N=\frac{24!}{4!}$$The "End of Shelf" markers function like this:  all the books (if any) up to the first marker go on the first shelf, the ones between the first and second marker (if any) go on the second shelf, ....    The books after the fourth and last marker (if any) go on the fifth shelf.